# What is the best way to Cache JSON request images for offline use?

Tags: ios, json, swift, caching, networking

I am new to networking and data caching in general. I am making a network request that returns me url strings which lead to images. I want to cache this data for offline use. What is the smartest way to do this using Apples frameworks(no third party libraries)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use third-party libs you have only two options: write your own solution or use a [NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/)

NSURLCache allows you to cache downloaded data in memory and on disk. The only issue with NSURLCache is that it **does not** guaranties everything you downloaded will be saved. For example it does not save (at least in iOS8) files that are bigger than 5% of the maximum disk usage. Also cache storage could be erased if device is out of the disk space. So NSURLCache usually is not suitable if you need a fully working offline solution. But it works great if you just need to reduce a network usage.

You could also read about NSURLCache [here](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is you increase the NSURLCache size using this   init(memoryCapacity memoryCapacity: Int,
       diskCapacity diskCapacity: Int,
           diskPath path: String?)       I need to save the data for offline use!

Comment: You can try to increase disk capacity but in general NSURLCache does not guarantees you everything will be saved. For example it could have some other hidden rules except this 5% one.